# Remove nano seconds from "Time" SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following code in SQL

```
select "Time" 
from Order
```

which returns - `09:10:11.0000000`

How do I format this to give me just the `hh:mm:ss` ?

Comment: You should first google before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, [time], 20) as 'Time' 
from Order
```

Answer (score 1):

TIME_FORMAT(time, '%T') will help you.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time, '%T') AS newTime FROM Order
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the SQL implementation, but for SQL Server you should probably use the [CONVERT() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp).

Alternatively you could perform a substring on what is currently returned, or even a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the field with date/time Styles.

Styles 20,108 will do the job:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, [time], 108) as 'Time' from Order
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, [time], 20) as 'Time' from Order
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the value to `time(0)`. The value in parentheses specifies the fractional seconds precision.

```
select cast([Time] as time(0)) as [Time]
```

[time (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)